# Delay new page load until animation is complete

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to do a quick animation of a div before leaving a page when a navigation link is clicked. How do I pull this off? I am having issues completing the animating before the new page is loaded. The animation starts then the page is loaded before the div can get moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var el = document.querySelector(".myelement");


el.addEventListener("animationstart", function() {}, false);
el.addEventListener("animationend", function() {el.onclick = navigateTo;}, false);
el.addEventListener("animationiteration", function() {}, false);

el.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', 
function( event ) { alert( "Finished transition!" ); }, false );

function navigateTo() {
  location.href=this.href;
}
```

[Using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

[GlobalEventHandlers.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick)

Comment: I put this at the bottom of my onclick animation function: elm.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd',function( event ) { elm.style.display = 'none'; location.href = "About.html"; }, false);
    elm.addEventListener('animationend',function( event ) { elm.style.display = 'none'; location.href = "About.html"; }, false);
    elm.addEventListener('oanimationend',function( event ) { elm.style.display = 'none'; location.href = "About.html"; }, false);  Seems to work!  Suggestions welcome.

Comment: `'animationend',` not `'oanimationend',`